# Qt3d. Отрисовка прозрачного QSphereMesh поверх треугольников

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Есть функция, которая рисует треугольники через обертку над OpenGL.

Я рисую два треугольника по нажатию кнопки (функция on_openMapPushButton_clicked()).

Далее я рисую сферу, которая находится над этими треугольниками. И теперь, я вижу, что сфера над одним треугольником отрисовывается правильно, но второй треугольник рисуется поверх сферы, почему-то.

Если я снова нажимаю на кнопку отрисовки треугольников, то сфера отрисовывется поверх двух треугольников.

Когда нажимаю на кнопку третий раз, то ситуация возвращается к первоначальной.

При четвертом нажатии сфера снова отрисовывается поверх и так далее.

Если я использую QPhongMaterial вместо QPhongAlphaMaterial, то сфера отрисовывается всегда поверх, как и должно быть.

Не понимаю, в чем дело и как сделать, чтобы сфера отрисовывалась всегда сверху.

**Фрагмент, рисующий прозрачную сферу:**

```
selectModel_ = new Qt3DExtras::QSphereMesh(selectEntity_);
selectModel_->setRadius(75);
selectModel_->setSlices(150);

selectMaterial_ = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongAlphaMaterial(selectEntity_);
selectMaterial_->setAmbient(QColor(28, 61, 136));
selectMaterial_->setDiffuse(QColor(11, 56, 159));
selectMaterial_->setSpecular(QColor(10, 67, 199));
selectMaterial_->setShininess(0.8f);

selectEntity_->addComponent(selectModel_);
selectEntity_->addComponent(selectMaterial_);
```

**Функция отрисовки треугольника drawTriangles:**

```
void drawTriangles(QPolygonF triangles, QColor color){
    int numOfVertices = triangles.size();

    // Создаем и заполняем вершинный буфер
    QByteArray bufferBytes;
    bufferBytes.resize(3 * numOfVertices * static_cast<int>(sizeof(float)));
    float *positions = reinterpret_cast<float*>(bufferBytes.data());

    for(auto point : triangles){
        *positions++ = static_cast<float>(point.x());
        *positions++ = 0.0f; //We need to drow only on the surface
        *positions++ = static_cast<float>(point.y());
    }

    geometry_ = new Qt3DRender::QGeometry(mapEntity_);
    auto *buf = new Qt3DRender::QBuffer(geometry_);
    buf->setData(bufferBytes);

    positionAttribute_ = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute(mapEntity_);
    positionAttribute_->setName(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::defaultPositionAttributeName());
    positionAttribute_->setVertexBaseType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::Float); //В буфере у нас будут флоаты
    positionAttribute_->setVertexSize(3); // Размер одной вершины
    positionAttribute_->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::VertexAttribute); // Тип атрибута
    positionAttribute_->setByteStride(3 * sizeof(float)); // Шаг между вершинами
    positionAttribute_->setBuffer(buf); // Сам буфер
    geometry_->addAttribute(positionAttribute_); // Добавляем атрибут в наш Qt3DRender::QGeometry

    // Создаем и заполняем индексный буфер
    QByteArray indexBytes;
    indexBytes.resize(numOfVertices * static_cast<int>(sizeof(unsigned int))); // start to end
    unsigned int *indices = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(indexBytes.data());

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < static_cast<unsigned int>(numOfVertices); ++i) {
        *indices++ = i;
    }

    auto *indexBuffer = new Qt3DRender::QBuffer(geometry_);
    indexBuffer->setData(indexBytes);

    indexAttribute_ = new Qt3DRender::QAttribute(geometry_); // Создаем индексный атрибут
    indexAttribute_->setVertexBaseType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::UnsignedInt); // Тип данных в индексном буфере
    indexAttribute_->setAttributeType(Qt3DRender::QAttribute::IndexAttribute); // Тип атрибута
    indexAttribute_->setBuffer(indexBuffer); // Сам индексный буфер
    indexAttribute_->setCount(static_cast<unsigned int>(numOfVertices)); // Количество вершин, как я понял
    geometry_->addAttribute(indexAttribute_); // Добавляем атрибут в наш Qt3DRender::QGeometry

    shape_ = new Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer(mapEntity_);
    shape_->setPrimitiveType(Qt3DRender::QGeometryRenderer::Triangles);
    shape_->setGeometry(geometry_); // Устанавливаем нашу геометрию

    //Создаем материал
    material_ = new Qt3DExtras::QPhongMaterial(mapEntity_);
    material_->setAmbient(color);

    trianglesEntity_ = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(mapEntity_);
    trianglesEntity_->addComponent(shape_); // Добавляем наш рисунок
    trianglesEntity_->addComponent(material_); // Добавляем наш материал
}
```

**Функция обработки кнопки on_openMapPushButton_clicked():**

```
void on_openMapPushButton_clicked()
{
    clearMap(); //Реализация ниже
    QPolygonF triangle1;
    triangle1 << QPointF( 0 ,-1000) << QPointF(0 ,1000) << QPointF(1000, -1000);
    drawTriangles(triangle1, Qt::black);

    QPolygonF triangle2;
    triangle2 << QPointF(-1000,-1000) << QPointF(-100,1000) << QPointF(-100,-1000);
    drawTriangles(triangle2, Qt::red);
}
```

**Функция очистки карты clearMap():**

```
void clearMap()
{
    if(mapEntity_){
        delete mapEntity_;
        mapEntity_ = nullptr;
        mapEntity_ = new Qt3DCore::QEntity(view3dRootEntity_);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Моя ошибка заключалась в том, что я создавал и удалял Entities в не правильном порядке.

В псевдокоде правильный порядок выглядит следующим образом:

```
clearTriangles();
clearSphere();       
drawTriangles();
drawSphere();
```

В ответах английской версии моего вопроса есть полезная информация о том, как еще можно менять порядок отрисовки, используя QSortPolicy или два FrameGraph: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55001233/qt3d-draw-transparent-qspheremesh-over-triangles